# Подготавливаемые запросы

Tags: php, mysqli

Всем добрый день!
Не совсем понимаю, почему при формировании запросов с помощью mysqli мы можем **присвоить значения переменным после того, как передали их в метод** `bind_param`?

```
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'Phil', '123', 'publications');
if ($conn->connect_error) die($conn->connect_error);

$stmt = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO classics VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)');
$stmt->bind_param('sssss', $author, $title, $category, $year, $isbn);

$author = 'Emily Brontë';
$title = 'Wuthering Height';
$category = 'Classic fiction';
$year = '1847';
$isbn = '9780553212587';

$stmt->execute();
printf("%d ROW inserted.\n", $stmt->affected_rows);
$stmt->close();
$conn->close();
```

А вот мой код, в котором я пытаюсь воспользоваться такой же возможностью. Но на экран ничего не выводится.

```
class test_class
{
    public $variable = 'default value';
    
    function give_param($variable)
    {
        $this->variable = $variable;
    }
    
    function execute()
    {
        echo $this->variable;
    }
}

$obj = new test_class();

$obj->give_param($variable);

$variable = 'abc';

$obj->execute();
```

Comment: совет - никогда так `die($conn->connect_error);` не делайте. Посмотрите в мануале, [как правильно соединяться](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php#example-1402)

Comment: Большое спасибо, что приняли мой ответ. мне не важна эта галочка, но важно чтобы в принятом ответе было предупреждение.

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это хороший вопрос, и у него есть два ответа - теоретический и практический.

### Теоретический ответ

состоит в том, что переменная в bind_param передаётся *по ссылке*. Если посмотреть на описание функции в мануале, то можно увидеть значок & перед именем переменной. Вот это оно и есть.
Почитать про ссылки можно [в мануале](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.references.whatdo.php).

Если очень грубо, то мы передаем в функцию не значение, а только *имя*  переменной (хотя корректнее говорить - ссылку на переменную), с которой будем работать. Одним из побочных эффектов этого будет возможность работать с переменной, которая ещё не определена на момент вызова функции.

### Практический ответ:

Почему это сделано? Передача по ссылке нужна для того, чтобы можно было сначала подготовить запрос и привязать к нему переменные, а потом несколько раз вызвать execute, с разными значениями:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE users SET status = ? WHERE id = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $status, $id);
foreach ($data as $id => $status) {
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

### Важное предупреждение

Злоупотреблять таким подходом не стоит. Если нет серьёзных причин передавать переменную по ссылке, **этого делать ни в коем случае не стоит.** Вы на собственном примере убедились, что такой подход запутывает разработчика и усложняет понимание кода.

Поэтому в вашем собственном варианте просто определяйте переменную до использования.  Поскольку в вашем случае нет ни одной причины делать по-другому.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы посмотрите [определение метода bind_param](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php), то он принимает не переменные, а ссылки на переменные &$var. Читайте как используются ссылки на переменные в PHP.

```
class test_class
{
    public $variable = 'default value';
    
    function give_param(&$variable)
    {
        $this->variable = &$variable;
    }
    
    function execute()
    {
        echo $this->variable;
    }
}

$obj = new test_class();

$obj->give_param($variable);

$variable = 'abc';

$obj->execute();
```

Comment: Один вопрос - зачем?

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Теперь я всё понял.

Comment: @Ипатьев, что зачем? Зачем так сделали в bind_param? Не знаю, не вижу никаких сложностей с тем, чтобы определить переменные до начала запроса или переопределить их позже. Ответ лишь поясняет этот момент.

Comment: Я имел в виду, зачем в вашем коде передача по ссылке

Comment: @Ипатьев, для демонстрации конечно) Чтобы было понятно, почему у автора не работает его код, а у bind_param он работает. Я же все-таки использую код автора из вопроса, а не придумываю свой.